# Losing votes on voting down - Accepted Answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, downvoted-questions

If voting down on an answer cost -1 Reputation

Shouldn't voting down an accepted answer cost more reputation points?

Comment: Just because the answer is accepted? Or is there a specific reason behind this?

Comment: Why would it have to cost more? The accepted answer mark is set by *one* user, and that user could be wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, yes because it is accepted, voting down on it should cost more than a normal answer

Comment: But why? ------

Comment: @Pëkka because it is accepted, someone must be very sure and ready to sacrifice more points on it. this is what i suggest

Comment: @simsim but why? I've seen plenty of accepted answers that are dead wrong. Why should there be less of an incentive to downvote them? Arguably, incorrect accepted answers need downvoting *more* because they send the wrong signal to the world

Comment: What if you downvote and it is accepted later?  You'd lose another point then.  So you wouldn't know how many points you would lose for downvoting an answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, good point, I didn't think of this scenario. but for the case when it was already accepted, and you want to downvote it.

Comment: @simsim Reputation is later adjusted for such things.  This is just one reason that it's a bad idea to lose more for downvoting an accepted answer.

Comment: Considering you just asked a question about why you should lose reputation at all for downvoting an accepted answer, I find this question incredibly puzzling. "Don't punish me for downvoting... actually, punish me MORE for downvoting!"

Comment: You should accept the answer - then downvote it.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg that’s actually fairly normal on per-site metas (at least for me), but then again, per-site metas don’t have rep anyways

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Shouldn't voting down an accepted answer cost more reputation points?

No.

An incorrect accepted answer is even worse than an incorrect regular answer, because the accept mark suggests some form of authoritativeness.

Voting is the community's main mechanism to alert other users to the answer's incorrectness, and create an incentive for its author to fix it.

Making it harder to downvote incorrect accepted answers would be counter-productive.

Comment: Free downvotes on accepted answers :-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 haha... that's exactly the comment I was thinking of leaving!

Comment: Well, free downvotes will be awesome, but it will be miss. But still, even if downvoting is free, I stick to my opinion, accepted answer should have a different treatment

Comment: @simsim Yet you have not offered even a single reason as to why you feel that making such a change would improve the site.  You've stated that you think it should happen with literally zero supporting evidence/reasoning.