# How can I cut my reputation losses?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I have asked a question, with good intentions, but it seems that it was totally not welcomed by the community. So, how can I cut the reputation losses from that question?

It has an answer, so I can't delete it. I flagged it, but I currently still lose some reputation because of it. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Is this on meta or the main site?

Comment: Meta, this applies on any I believe

Comment: If its [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218184/losing-votes-on-voting-down-accepted-answer) you can accept an answer if you accept the positions posted there. That will usually slow downvotes. But its likely it will soon slip away into the higher pages where people are less likely to see it anyway.

Comment: @RichardTingle, I posted the question yesterday, till now, it gets downvoted

Comment: @simsim indeed, and each edit gives it a new group of people to see it and disagree with it. I advise you to just let it age off the front page. Commenting to say you accept the community position can also help

Comment: I do accept the community position, if there is an idea, the community decides whether it is good or bad

Comment: if it helps meta rep is seperate from main site rep. Think of it like an election. You lost this year, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't run again next time

Comment: Yeah, I got a tough crowd this year :)

Comment: @simsim honestly, -22 in about 1 day isn't that terrible.  I've witnessed some that have gone to -40 or -50 is similar times.  As others have said, the more attention you call to it by editing and talking about it, the most views you'll get and the more downvotes.  Let it fade into the sunset.  You might pick up 1 or 2 votes every once in a while, but they likely will be few and far between once the post falls off the first page/

Comment: @psubsee2003, thats why I didn't link to my question. hoping it will fade away "quickly"

Comment: It's also worth remembering that you've regained over half of your losses from just the 5 upvotes here

Comment: Perhaps make a new feature-request for free downvotes on accepted answers.

Comment: @BillWoodger, I've already took many losses from that one, your suggestion will make it a worse question I think

Comment: @RichardTingle, you are right, it is a good experience for me, and a good practice to others

Comment: Well, that comment on your question got eighteen votes last time I looked...

Comment: related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/the-i-get-it-reputation-problem)

Comment: @BillWoodger it was a joke comment, and I'll bet 75% of the upvotes on that comment knew it was a joke (or I hope they were).  A real feature request with that idea will get downvoted amost as much as the original feature request.

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, I've been pondering some old questions where there are high numbers of votes for an accepted answer but where the answer is "aged" at best, as time has moved on. It may then be confusing for a searcher finding the answer. I don't think the rep should be lost, but trying to think of a way of presenting a better order of answers to searchers. Sorry to have missed the joke...

Comment: @BillWoodger in theory, the idea isn't bad, but the current system limits (you can't delete an accepted answer) make it impractical.  Plus, I'm not a fan of free answer downvoting (even if it is the accepted answer).  The -1 makes you think before casting votes on answers to make sure the downvote is warranted.  I think there are better ways to deal with it.

Comment: @BillWoodger If you haven't see this yet, I think you might be interested in the discussion in [Do accepted answers still serve a useful purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose)

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes, thanks. There's a few questions here which cover aspects. An answer I know of on SO, and I'd guess it is not the only one, with > 50 Upvotes, Accepted, 20k+ rep user, but it is not good. It is from several years ago. How to get any answer to appear above that, is what I'm wondering...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't point at them and go *"How can I stop the downvotes on that one? That one over there. That question you all find so bad."*. That will have the opposite result.

The questions will most likely remain, but in some time people will have forgotten about them, and they will no longer appear on the front page or on top of most lists. Just move on and focus your attention on better things, if there is no way for you to rescue the question in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that you think it would be the same for meta or a main site, but it wouldn't. On meta, you can get downvotes for a beautifully written question that people disagree with. if you suggest changing the rules, this is a risk you run, and it's best just to let it drop once you realize your suggestion wasn't well-received. On all the metas other than this, rep doesn't even exist - your meta rep comes from your main site activities - so there's no harm.

On a main site, though, you should fix your question. Make it clear and well written. If the answerer was able to guess that your problem was with something you didn't even put in the question, go back and put it in the question. This will help people reading the question and answer pair later. Editing it will put it on the front page where it may get upvotes, and over time Googlers will come to it as well. Since upvotes give more rep than downvotes take, you can have a negative score for your question but not have lost rep from it. And the world has an answer that will help them.